# Trigger only on specific changes to data

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Someone has helped me write the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_stats AFTER UPDATE ON user_hours FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO hours_statistics (user_id, opportunity_id, completed_hours) VALUES
(OLD.user_id, OLD.opportunity_id, -OLD.completed_hours),
(NEW.user_id, NEW.opportunity_id, +NEW.completed_hours)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
completed_hours = completed_hours + VALUES(completed_hours);
```

However, the trigger should only run for:

```
UPDATE user_hours JOIN user_calendar USING (user_calendar_id, opportunity_id)
SET    user_hours.completed_hours = agreed_hours,
user_hours.hours_committed = 'completed'
WHERE  user_hours.hours_committed = 'accepted' 
AND user_hours.completed_hours IS NULL
AND user_calendar.date_start = CURRENT_DATE();
```

As it stands currently, if admin or user completed_hours are manually adjusted, the update trigger still runs. I would like to add some IF statement to the code but my attempts all failed to create the trigger.

I'm looking for something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_stats AFTER UPDATE ON user_hours FOR EACH ROW
IF hours_committed = 'completed' THEN
INSERT INTO hours_statistics (user_id, opportunity_id, completed_hours) VALUES
(OLD.user_id, OLD.opportunity_id, -OLD.completed_hours),
(NEW.user_id, NEW.opportunity_id, +NEW.completed_hours)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
completed_hours = completed_hours + VALUES(completed_hours);
END IF
END
```

Anyone able to help, just dont want the Trigger running unless specific condition is met, annoying that the code works we need but this makes a problem for days outside of the adjustment query being ran.

thanks in advance.

Mark

Comment: Do you mean `hours_commited = 'completed'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigger will always run, you need to add that condition to the body of the trigger, and compare the newly updated column (`new.column`):

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER update_stats AFTER UPDATE ON user_hours 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.hours_committed = 'completed' THEN
    INSERT INTO hours_statistics (user_id, opportunity_id, completed_hours) VALUES
      (OLD.user_id, OLD.opportunity_id, -OLD.completed_hours),
      (NEW.user_id, NEW.opportunity_id, +NEW.completed_hours)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      completed_hours = completed_hours + VALUES(completed_hours);
  END IF;
END//
```

Comment: That gives an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7
END IF END;
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF END' at line 1

Comment: Is there a column named `hours_completed`? Or is it `hours_commited`?

Comment: Which table should that reference?

Comment: Same issue, changed to hours_committed: [ERROR in query 1] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7
[ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF
END' at line 1

Comment: Still same issues guys and thank you for assisting so far :-)

Comment: Unknown column 'hours_commited' in 'NEW' (EDIT: Was a typo on your part of the code, testing things now will get back to you soon :-)

Comment: It does not seem to be triggering anything now, i've inserted hours_completed for a row as 8, then set completed from the enum values and no update is setting new hours in hours_statistics? Any ideas?

Comment: But are you setting the  column `hours_commited` to `complete` on the same update statement?

Comment: Yea that's right, first i set the hours then completed, should this happen as one update for it to trigger? or can we have it another way? Ultimate idea is that my trigger runs ONCE per day on specific conditions

Comment: The trigger will fire any time you update anything on the `user_hours` table. However, it will only enter the `UPDATE` part of the trigger, when you explicitly update the hours_commited column, i.e., `SET hours_commited = 'complete'`.

Comment: So we could use that daily like this? e.g. run our:
 `code`   UPDATE user_hours JOIN user_calendar USING (user_calendar_id, opportunity_id)
    SET    user_hours.completed_hours = agreed_hours,
    user_hours.hours_committed = 'completed'
    WHERE  user_hours.hours_committed = 'accepted' 
    AND user_hours.completed_hours IS NULL
    AND user_calendar.date_start = CURRENT_DATE();`/code`

Comment: I only want update to occur based on that query or similar to it, altering the date for the update of hours_committed to completed, then and only then should an insert / update be made to hours_statistics, hope im making sense :-) and thanks so much for your help, once we get this solved i'll mark as answered :)

Comment: @MarkH: Yes, you could do that, as long as `hours_committed` is updated to `complete`, the `IF` condition on the trigger should execute (`NEW` refers to the newly updated row of `user_hours`).

Comment: Thanks João, if I needed to do anything else the trigger could easily add an ELSE condition yes? you have been very helpful :-)

Comment: @MarkH: Indeed, just add your additional logic to the `ELSE` part. You're welcome :)